# How to parse an instance of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to get date, weekday, month and year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails version `5.2.2.1` and have instances of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` being returned from a `starts_on` field in multiple records.

One example evaluates to this:

`Thu, 05 Apr 2019 16:32:41 BST +01:00`

Can someone show me a good way to convert it to each of these four formats:

`5 April 2019` (day rounded to one digit where possible, month as full word, year as digit)

`05` (day as two digit number, with leading 0 retained for 1-9)

`Thursday` (day as full, unabbreviated word)

`April` (month as full, unabbreviated word)

I couldn't find a solution elsewhere on here that contains an efficient way to obtain the full, unabbreviated month and weekday names.

The solution will of course need to work on an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance modelling any date, not just my example of April 5th.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)? For example, the token for unabbreviated month is `%B`, and unabbreviated week day is `%A`. Is there something about the documentation that's unclear to you? If so, how could we (the community) improve it?

Comment: You can also prevent duplication by giving names to your custom formats - like [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/custom-formats-for-datetime).

Comment: @TomLord Thanks. That documentation appears to be for the Ruby `Time` class. I was looking at the methods in the documentation for `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, but I missed the part where it says those instances implement the same API as Ruby `Time` so are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout `ruby` [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html), [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html) and [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

```
Date.today    
=>Thu, 16 May 2019

Date.today.strftime('%A')  
=> "Thursday" # you week name

Date.today.strftime('%B')
=> "May" # month name  

Date.today.strftime('%d %A %b %Y')
=> "16 Thursday May 2019"

10.days.ago.strftime('%-d %b %Y')
=> "6 May 2019" # gives date without 0
```